# Cómo guardar cada elemento de un array con ciclo for

Tags: javascript

1. Quiero crear una función que individualice cada elemento de un array dado
   es decir; me guarde cada elemento en variables diferentes.
2. como los arrays asignados nunca son iguales, pueden ser Int, float o string; es incierta la longitud y tipo de elemento.
3. El uso de cada variable no esta incluido en la pregunta

Ejemplo:

```javascript
var elementos = [...,Carlos, 4.6, 34, true];
function separarElemDeArray(array){
   //variable a llenar...[],[],[]
   for (array i = 0; i < array; i++) {
      //operación para llenar las variables
      return variables
   }
}
/*debería resultar:
var a = Carlos,
var b = 4.6,
var c = 34,
var d = true,
...Según array original
*/
```

4. Esto se puede realizar en javascript?

Comment: No sé a qué llamas *métodos tradicionales*. Por otro lado, considera añadir un [mcve], ya que no somos adivinos para saber lo que tienes y lo que intentas hacer. La explicación de tu pregunta no es tan clara como piensas. Saludos

Comment: lo que quiero es crear una función que me individualice cada elemento del array asignado en la función, para trabajar de diferentes formas sobre cada uno de los elementos ya individualizados, como es una función se le podría asignar cualquier tipo de array y por eso puede tener cualquier longitud o tipos de elementos, lo que busco es individualizar cada elemento del array.

Comment: @carlosing tu explicación sigue siendo muy ambigua, por favor, para poder ayudarte edita la pregunta añadiendo más detalles y el código que has intentado.

Comment: podrías crear un objeto `{"a": "Carlos", "b":4.6, ...}`

Comment: siii, pero recuerda que el array original puede ser cualquiera, y tengo el problema que si indexo no tengo los parámetros o los 'id', se que tengo limitar las variables a crear con .lenght , pero no se como asignarlas dentro del for.

Comment: obviamente creas el objeto dependiendo del array \\_(°-°)_/

Comment: @carlosing por favor lee esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/479860/86914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cada iteración de for() suma 1 a i hasta que sea igual a la extensión del arreglo, con ayuda de switch(), evalua cada cambio de i, asignandole a una variable el valor de lo que sea i en el arreglo.

Debido a la indexación desde 0 de JS, empieza a contar los casos a partir de 0 y no de 1.

Recuerda siempre poner entre comillas simples o dobles las cadenas de caracteres.

```js
var elementos = ['Carlos', 4.6, 34,true];
var a, b, c, d;

    function separarElemDeArray(elementos){
        for (var i=0;i<elementos.length;i++){
            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    a = elementos[i];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    b = elementos[i];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    c = elementos[i];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    d = elementos[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

separarElemDeArray(elementos);
console.log(a,b,c,d);
```

Comment: Claramente se dice que el arreglo puede variar, por lo que esto no serviría completamente si le paso un array de 10 elementos. Como dije en mi comentario, crear un objeto es lo mejor.

Comment: GRACIAS, su ayuda me ha servido, aunque no es perfecto he podido independizar en variables por aparte de un array original, tengo que agregar mas variables de lo normal así queden en undefinet las sobrantes, pero ya es un inicio; muchas GRACIAS.

Answer (score 2):

### Primer punto

> 1. Quiero crear una función que individualice cada elemento de un array dado es decir; me guarde cada elemento en variables diferentes.

Bien, para cumplir el primer punto de tu pregunta (sin tener en cuenta los demás puntos) **si o si** debes conocer el tamaño de tu arreglo para llevar a cabo esto de "me guarde cada elemento en variables diferentes".

Esto lo podemos lograr fácilmente de la siguiente manera:

```js
let elementos = ['Carlos', 4.6, 34,true];
let [a, b, c, d] = elementos; // Conocemos la cantidad de elementos

console.log(a, b, c, d);

let elementos2 = [1, true, "dos"];
[a, b, c] = elementos2; // Conocemos la cantidad de elementos

console.log(a, b, c);
```

Esto de conocer el tamaño del arreglo de antemano es porque si tuviéramos un arreglo con más o con menos elementos, entonces nos faltarían o sobrarían variables.

Ejemplo con menos elementos en el array:

```js
let elementos = ['Carlos', 4.6, 34];
let [a, b, c, d] = elementos; // La variable "d" no tiene valor

console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

Ejemplo con más elementos en el array:

```js
let elementos = ['Carlos', 4.6, 34, true, "abc"];
let [a, b, c, d] = elementos; // El elemento "abc" no se asigna a ninguna variable

console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

---

### Segundo punto

> 2. Como los arrays asignados nunca son iguales, pueden ser Int, float o string; es incierta la longitud y tipo de elemento.

Recordando el **punto 1** tenemos entonces que la solución anterior no serviría ya que como establece el **punto 2** "es incierta la longitud" (Obviamos los del "tipo de elemento" ya que javascript no es un lenguaje tipado).

---

### Tercer y último punto

> 3. El uso de cada variable no esta incluido en la pregunta

Al no proveernos de un ejemplo de para qué quieres estas variables, es un poco complicado entender tu acercamiento al problema.

### Solución

Sin embargo, creo que más allá de qué es lo que vayas a hacer con esas "variables individuales" de las cuales no conoces la cantidad a priori, puedo recomendarte una estructura de datos que resuelve los siguientes problemas:

1. Puedes tener variables individuales dentro de esta estructura
2. No hace falta conocer la cantidad de variables de antemano
3. Puedes meter cualquier tipo de dato (enteros, flotantes, string, booleanos, etc)

Esta estructura de datos es ni mas ni menos que el [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) que ya estás usando.

Recuerda que un arreglo en javascript es una lista de elementos que puede crecer de manera dinámica (no tienes que definir su largo de antemano) y que puede almacenar elementos de distintos tipos:

> `var elementos = ['Carlos', 4.6, 34,true];`

El arreglo `elementos` de tu pregunta ya lo está haciendo.

Bien, por último, antes de que me digas "pero con un arreglo no tengo variables individuales" pues te tengo que decir que te equivocas.

Un arreglo se puede ver como una lista de variables individuales a las cuales puedes acceder por medio de índices.

Por lo tanto si no conoces el largo del arreglo ni los tipos si o si tendrás que usar un bucle `for` o un `while` dependiendo de qué quieras hacer.

Y para chequear el tipo de dato puedes hacer uso de [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Creo que simplemente tienes una pequeña confusión de conceptos.

Espero haberte ayudado y no dudes en comentar si no se entiende algún punto.

Comment: ESTA BUENO, GRACIAS

Comment: Si contestó tu pregunta considera marcarla como respuesta aceptada. Y si todavia tienes alguna duda, comentalo aquí y agregaré algún ejemplo si lo necesitas Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

GRACIAS a la ayuda de un compañero pude guardar cada elemento de un array original en variables diferentes, aun hay problemas para determinar el numero de variables a asignar. estas variables tienen el objetivo de ser comparadas con otro array bidimensional, es decir el [0][0:23] ,el [2][2:5] y el [7] [7:-11.7] tengo que escoger el que tenga el mayor valor

```
 var ciclosC4=
    [
        0:23,
        1:15.2,
        2:5,
        3:8.5,
        4:-1.7,
        5:null,
        6:2.3,
        7:-11.7,
        8:-3.4,
        9:49
    ]
```

```
var numParaC4=[0,2,7]
var elementos = numParaC4;
var a, b, c, d;

    function separarElemDeArray(elementos){
        for (var i=0;i<elementos.length;i++){
            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    a = elementos[i];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    b = elementos[i];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    c = elementos[i];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    d = elementos[i];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

separarElemDeArray(elementos);

    var n1c4 =a
         console.log(n1c4);
    var n2c4 =b
        console.log(n2c4);
    var n3c4 =c
        console.log(n3c4);
    var n4c4 =d
        console.log(n4c4);
```